# How to implement routing in PHP?

Tags: php, routes

I searched for it over internet and what I found was all very complex. I want a simple alternative where can I redirect my users to their desired page or to a 404 error page if the page cannot be found. I have done routing in node.js and it was easy though I didn't find any examples or tutorials for it in PHP in almost all the famous PHP books. Please try to provide a method that is not specifically made for Apache, i.e .htaccess so that can be used anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Bro I asked for a example or a method. I just said that I couldn't find this in any book...

Comment: I said I had done it using .htaccess but I want an overall solution to it... It would be appreciated if you help..

Comment: It's rare to implement an actual web server in PHP, so comparing it to node where that practice is common is a bit strange.  If you set them up in a similar way, the solution is probably very similar.  Otherwise, it will involve web server configuration to rewrite paths.  There are probably thousands of php routing libraries out there, so this is pretty broad.

Comment: @Devon So how should I restrict my users from accessing certain files and redirect them to an 404 error page if their requested page cannot be found?

Comment: You should look for some library and check how they did it. There are also a bunch of tutorials about this out there. SO isn't a tutorial sites where you ask for examples or discuss architectures. SO is for when you have code but are stuck on something specific. This question is simply off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Bilal - You may find it easier to achieve what you want using one of the many PHP frameworks. If you want to avoid frameworks maybe something like klein.php will do what you want.

Comment: Still too broad.  How are you planning to serve these pages/files?  Maybe you should look into using a framework like Laravel, Symfony, Yii, or CodeIgniter if you're having trouble getting started?  All of these have routing implementations built in along with predefined rules to insert into your web server virtualhost.

Comment: @FergalAndrews Can you explain in answer something about klein.php?

Comment: This is the github page. I haven't used it so can't say how good it is. If you google 'klein.php' you will find more info> https://github.com/klein/klein.php

Comment: @FergalAndrews Thanks and please if you want me to give more details than don't down vote. I can put up my .htaccess code here to tell what I had done but I never asked for suggestions, I am asking for a detailed example...

Comment: ...or simply google "php router". Just tried it and found multiple routers + tutorials on how to build one...

Answer (score 1):

From seeing comments I can say you need php code line for redirecting user from restricted page to 404 page not found. Use header('Location: page') for this . Example:-

```
header('Location: 404.php');
die;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I mean if you request a page that is not available how PHP can handle it?

Comment: Php is an server sided language for pages.  See the full form Personal Home Page. Use .htaccess for routing or apache or use a PHP framework like laravel as they have routing prebuild with pretty much less amount of coding required.

Comment: Ok thanks please up vote my question as I need some more answers from some experts..... I don't get why my question is down voted my SO moderators?